sendcmpct message
I'm trying to connect to a local testnet3 node with a custom Rust code.
After handshake, node sends a sendcmpct message as per BIP152.
The message I receive is
[11, 17, 9, 7, 115, 101, 110, 100, 99, 109, 112, 99, 116, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 233, 47, 94, 248]
where
11, 17, 9, 7 is the network
115, 101, 110, 100, 99, 109, 112, 99, 116, 0, 0, 0 is the command (12 bytes)
9, 0, 0, 0 is the length of the contained payload (little-endian)
and 233, 47, 94, 248 is the checksum.
There is no other bytes in the message.
I'm also verified that the checksum is correct.
Why the message declare a 9 bytes payload (correctly, as per BIP) but no real payload in the message?
Thanks for any help.

What software are you talking to? This sounds broken.

Sorry, my fault. Reading the socket, I was reusing the same buffer and truncating it again and again.

I’m voting to close this question because the author realised they had made a programming error.
